# Trying to find Mentor/mentee pairs that have not submitted a certain report

Tags: sql, inner-join, outer-join

Trying to find the mentor-mentee groups that  have not submitted a specific report (reported = 147). All the pairs have submitted reports but I need the ones who have specifically not submitted 147 yet.

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     e2.Firstname Mentor_FN
    ,e2.lastname Mentor_LN
    ,e1.Firstname Mentee_FN
    ,e1.lastname Mentee_LN
    ,r.ReportID
FROM
MentorRelationshipStaging m
INNER JOIN Employee e1
    ON e1.EmployeeCode = m.MenteeCode
INNER JOIN Employee e2
    ON e2.EmployeeCode = m.MentorCode
INNER JOIN UserReport ur1 
    ON ur1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Report r 
    ON r.reportID = ur1.ReportID
```

DATABASE:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qphEq.jpg

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Try adding a filter to your last join as below

Comment: I assume that query return all the report submitted by Mentor/Mentee?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Only the Mentor can write the report?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes this query gives me All reports submitted between the two, where as I only need to know the pairs who have not submitted reportID 147. I wont have access to the schema until tomorrow and will update then.

Comment: Only the mentor can write the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT e2.Firstname Mentor_FN, e2.lastname Mentor_LN, e1.Firstname Mentee_FN, e1.lastname Mentee_LN
FROM MentorRelationshipStaging m INNER JOIN
     Employee e1
     ON e1.EmployeeCode = m.MenteeCode INNER JOIN
     Employee e2
     ON e2.EmployeeCode = m.MentorCode LEFT JOIN
     UserReport ur1
     ON ur.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e2.Firstname Mentor_FN, e2.lastname Mentor_LN, e1.Firstname Mentee_FN, e1.lastname Mentee_LN
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ur.ReportId = 147 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 ;
```

Or, if you don't want to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT e2.Firstname Mentor_FN, e2.lastname Mentor_LN, e1.Firstname Mentee_FN, e1.lastname Mentee_LN
FROM MentorRelationshipStaging m INNER JOIN
     Employee e1
     ON e1.EmployeeCode = m.MenteeCode INNER JOIN
     Employee e2
     ON e2.EmployeeCode = m.MentorCode LEFT JOIN
     UserReport ur1
     ON ur.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID AND ur.ReportId = 147
WHERE ur.EmployeeId IS NULL;
```

Notes:

- The key is the `LEFT JOIN` to be sure you get people who have submitted no reports.
- The `Reports` table is not needed, because the `ReportId` is in `UserReport`.
- I am a bit suspicious about the `JOIN` to `UserReport`.  You are suggesting that the "mentor" is always submitting the report.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     e2.Firstname Mentor_FN
    ,e2.lastname Mentor_LN
    ,e1.Firstname Mentee_FN
    ,e1.lastname Mentee_LN
    ,r.ReportID
FROM
MentorRelationshipStaging m
INNER JOIN Employee e1
    ON e1.EmployeeCode = m.MenteeCode
INNER JOIN Employee e2
    ON e2.EmployeeCode = m.MentorCode
INNER JOIN UserReport ur1 
    ON ur1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Report r 
    ON r.reportID = ur1.ReportID and ur1.ReportID=147
```

Comment: `I need the ones who have specifically not submitted 147 yet.`

Answer (score 0):

I can't be more specific because don't know your schema. But this is usually solve with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` using a conditional `COUNT`

```
 GROUP BY e2.Firstname
         ,e2.lastname
         ,e1.Firstname
         ,e1.lastname
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN reported = 147 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does give me the pairs who have submitted the report, however I'm looking for the pairs who do not have report 147 submitted.

Comment: You should check again because that is what this do. If you have report 147 then you can count it, if you dont the count should be 0